# Ufmt Format doesn't work on Py scripts with match case

Tags: python, format, match, case

I know match case is a pretty recent addition to Python. ufmt (v2.0.1) still doesn't format files with match case statements in them. Any workarounds? Thanks

Here's the last thing I get from terminal when I run `ufmt format` on such a file

```
libcst._exceptions.ParserSyntaxError: Syntax Error @ 11:19.
Incomplete input. Encountered 'unit', but expected ';', or 'NEWLINE'.

            match unit:
                  ^
```

Tried running `ufmt format` on file with match case statement in them. Expected the file to be formatted accordingly. Got errors and the file wasn't formatted

Answer (score 0):

This happen because µsort (the import sorter that µfmt uses) uses LibCST, which requires enabling its native Rust parser in order to support 3.10+ syntax, including match statements.

This is fixed in the latest version of µfmt (2.1.0) where it enables the LibCST native parser by default when formatting.

If you can't (or prefer not to) upgrade µfmt, then you can workaround this issue by setting `LIBCST_PARSER_TYPE=native` in your environment before running µfmt or µsort.

Comment: looks like I can't upgrade to the most recent version of ufmt. how could i edit that environment variable in my virtual env?

Comment: Depending on your OS, you can probably do something like `export LIBCST_PARSER_TYPE=native` in your shell before running µfmt.